# If duplicate, return the corresponding row value in Python Pandas

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to sort a column of excel to show duplicate Zip Codes. If there is a duplicate, I am trying to get pandas to look one column over from the duplicate zipcodes, sum the values, and create a new list with the duplicated/summed values. Currently I am able to create a list of all of the duplicates, but am lost as to what step I need to take next. Any help is appreciated as I am new to coding.

Example code below:

```
from collections import Counter

df = pd.read_excel(r'L:\FixedIncomeReport.xlsx')

zip_code = df['Zip']
quantity = df['Quantity']
Pair = list(zip(zip_code, quantity))
dups=[]
zipcount= list(Counter(i[0] for i in Pair).items())


#print(zipcount)
for i in zipcount:
    if i[1] > 1 :
        dups.append(i[0])

def variable(element):
    if (element in dups):
        return True 
    else:
        return False

filtered = filter(variable, (i[0] for i in Pair))


for item in filtered:
    print(item)

    if item in (i[0] for i in Pair):
        print(list(i[1] for i in Pair))
```

Comment: `df[df.duplicated(keep=False)].sum()`?

Comment: please show an example of your dataframe and your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a way to get information about duplicates in a pandas dataframe is to use the groupby function. You can group your dataframe by zipcode and count the number of occurrences and at the same time sum the quantity field.

In the code below I've created a simple dataframe of 10 Zipcodes with their respective Quantity, some zipcodes are duplicated. The code then performs the grouping, filters for duplicated zipcodes and outputs the two lists I think you need.

```
    import pandas as pd

    ## create sample dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Zip':['11111','00000','00001','11001','00000','11100','11111','00110','11011','00010'],
              'Quantity':[3,6,2,6,5,8,9,0,1,4]
              })

    ## group dataframe by Zip, count the number of occurrences and sum the Quantity field
    grouped_df = df.groupby('Zip')['Quantity'].agg(['sum','count']).reset_index()

    ## output the duplicated zipcodes as a dataframe with the number of occurrences and sum of quantity
    duplicated_df = grouped_df[grouped_df['count']>1]
    duplicated_df.columns = ['DuplicateZip','SumOfQuantity','NumOfOccurrences']

    ## output the duplicated zipcodes as a list
    duplicated_zipcodes_list = list(grouped_df[grouped_df['count']>1]['Zip'])

    ## output the sum of quantities for duplicated zipcodes as a list
    duplicated_zipcodes_quantitysum_list = list(grouped_df[grouped_df['count']>1]['sum'])
```

Comment: You're welcome! Can you upvote/accept my answer pls? I'm trying to build some reputation points thanks ;) @TimmyBoi